# Health check failures with HTTP/2 in an ALB target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

Despite enabling the HTTP/2 protocol in my Application Load Balancer (ALB) with a Target Group protocol version of HTTP/1.1, I encountered an "net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR" instead of the expected error message when certain APIs responded with error codes due to incorrect icon selection.

I tried by disabling HTTP/2 in the ALB, it is showing and responding with the correct expected error messages.

I believed there was an incompatibility issue between the Application Load Balancer (ALB) and the target group, so I attempted to resolve it by creating a new ALB with HTTP/2 support and configuring the target group to use HTTP/2 as well. The goal was to make them compatible. However, I am currently facing health check failures when using HTTP/2 with the target group in the ALB. Interestingly, when I used the same container with a different target group, it was able to successfully pass data using the HTTP/1.1 protocol. Could you please help me understand why the health checks are failing in the HTTP/2 configuration?